# pgfplot xbar legend ordering

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend, bar-chart

when I am drawing a xbar chart, I have troubles with the legend entries.
They appear to have the opposite ordering as I suppose they should have.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar]
  \addplot  coordinates {(2.659244418,1)};
  \addlegendentry{A}
  \addplot  coordinates {(18.95781994,1)};
  \addlegendentry{B}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Example plot]

Either the bar position should switch or the legend label position.
Somethings seems to be wrong here.

Maybe anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can reverse the order of the legend entries by setting `reverse legend`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xbar, reverse legend]
  \addplot  coordinates {(2.659244418,1)};
  \addlegendentry{A}
  \addplot  coordinates {(18.95781994,1)};
  \addlegendentry{B}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```